# Creating custom OpenLDAP schemas using existing attributes

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have implemented the following ldif file successfully:

```
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: schema

dn: cn=svcs,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: services
olcObjectClasses: ( 4.1.11 NAME 'svcs3User'
  MUST ( uid $ userPassword ) MAY ( mail ) AUXILIARY )
```

However, when I go to add information for this objectClass, not only is "cn" a required field, but I also get the following error, no matter what I do:

`Object Class Violation. Reason: Object Class Violation`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. The expected behavior is that I'd have an objectClass (svcs3User) and that it would have a username field (uid), a password field (userPassword), and an optional e-mail field (mail), with no other required entries.